# Etimología de "tarugo"

Tags: etimología

Revisando la etimología de *tortuga*, leo:

> [**tortuga**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=a8iZjLF)
>   `Del lat. tardío`*`tartarūchus`*`'demonio', y este del gr. ταρταροῦχος`*`tartaroûchos`*`'habitante del Tártaro o infierno'.`

Nada más verlo, *tartarūchus* me ha recordado a **tarugo** y a estas acepciones:

> [**tarugo**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZEoVrCW)
>
> 3. m. coloq. Hombre de mala traza pequeño y gordo.
> 4. m. coloq. Persona de rudo entendimiento.

Pero, como se puede observar, el DLE no indica el origen de esta palabra, al menos a día de hoy.

Pregunta: ¿cuál es el origen de la palabra **tarugo**? ¿Es posible que sea un cognado de *tortuga*?

Comment: You might be interested in the etymology of the English word tortoise https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tortoise which come from the same origins but the writer of that text is much less certain about the links to tartaruchus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corominas, en su Diccionario Etimológico, le dedica un espacio amplio, que se resume en:

> TARUGO 'clavija de madera', voz peculiar al cast. y al port., de **origen incierto, probablemente prerromano** y emparentado con los galos TARINCA 'perno o clavija' (irl. med. y mod. *tairnge*, fr. *taranche*, Rouergue *tarenco*) y TARATRUM (> cast. TALADRO): es posible que *TARÜCON existiera ya en el céltico de España con el sentido de 'clavija, tarugo'.

Resumiendo algo menos su texto:

- El vocablo no se encuentra en otros romances. Hay algunas formas diferentes  relacionadas con tarugo, como el gallego lucense *teregos* o *taragos*, el asturiano *tarucu*, etc.
- Descarta que proceda del árabe tárquwa 'clavícula, asa'.
- La acepción 'zoquete' es muy moderna, y todas las indicaciones antiguas apuntan hacia el sentido característico y específico de 'clavija que atraviesa o sujeta'.
- Recoge, pero duda, de la teoría de que deriva del lat. TORUS 'bulto, protuberancia (en el cuerpo humano, en una planta, etc.)', de donde viene el cast. tuero 'tronco rollizo' y su familia.
- Favorece la hipótesis de que viene, con otro sufijo, del mismo radical que el galo TARINCA. Señala la existencia de palabras irlandesas de forma y significado parecidos y supone un protocéltico *TARINGIA, casi idéntico al galo TARINCA, -INGA', y por otra parte el vocablo pertenece a la misma raíz céltica que el galo TARATRUM. "Ahora bien, si el céltico admitió las diferentes formaciones sufijales TAR-INCA, TAR-INGA, TAR-INGIA, TAR-ATRON, también tenemos derecho a suponer que formara un TAR-ÜCO-N y que en el Centro y Oeste peninsulares se reservara esta palabra arcaica para la clavija hecha de madera, correspondiente a un tipo cultural no menos arcaico".
- Considera inverosimil que "tarugo sea voz prerromana sin relación con estas palabras célticas." o que "tarugo salga de TARINCA, por un «cambio de sufijo» romance, muy arbitrario, y verdaderamente sorprendente siendo -ugo sufijo desusado en castellano".

Answer (score 3):

Estaría bien, pero parece que no va a ser así. Nos vamos a tener que contentar con descubrir que *tortuga* significó originalmente "yo vivo en el infierno".

Cuando el diccionario no admite etimología alguna es que no hay nada seguro (tampoco tengo claro qué diferencia hay entre que una voz no proponga etimología y que otra ponga "de origen incierto", lo mismo sería). La voz aparece en el etimológico de Corominas, con el siguiente texto:

> TARUGO, 1386, 'clavija de madera'. [...] Origen incierto. Probablemente prerromano y emparentado con el galo TARĬNCA 'perno o clavija' [que emparenta con "tranca"]. También con el céltico TARATRUM, de donde nuestro *taladro*. Es posible que venga de una base *TARŪCON ya formada en el céltico de España con el sentido de 'clavija', 'tarugo'.

Así que lo dicho, no hay nada seguro. La voz no proviene del latín, puesto que Nebrija en 1495 la traducía al latín como *subscus*, lo cual denota además que la palabra es harto antigua. Otra etimología propone el *Rosal* de 1611:

> Tarugo, como *Pterugo*, que del Griego quiere decir Ala, ó Aleta, porque tal hechura tenía el Tarugo que el Romano llamaba *subscus*; por lo qual en España y Francia los Carpinteros a los Tarugos, con que traban las tablas de los edificios, llaman Colas o Alas de Golondrinas. De aquí Vitrubio a la trabazón de el edificio llama *Ptera*.

En 1884 el DLE se animaba con otra etimología:

> Del sánscrito *tara*, taladrar.

Aunque para la edición de 1914 dicha etimología ya había desaparecido.